# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm working on a simple function whereby I have a table of rows and on each row is an editButton. In the onclick of the edit button, I am calling the bellow function and getting the error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

It points to line 1 of the php file which just has the doctype declaration (which seems to be fine when I load the page first - the error only occurs when I click on an edit button). Function below:

```
function editGUI(rowNum, carerName, carerAddress, carerMobile, carerID){
        row=document.getElementById('Row'+rowNum);
        row.innerHTML= '<tr id="Row' + i + '">\
                    <td><input type="text" value="' + carerName + '"></td>\
                    <td><input type="text" value="' + carerAddress + '"></td>\
                    <td><input type="text" value="' + carerMobile + '"></td>\
                    <td>  HISTORY  </td>\
                    <td><button onClick="editCarer('+carerID+');">EDIT</button></td>\
                    </tr>';
    };
```

Initial html is dynamically appended with javascrript and appears correctly on screen:

```
for (var i = 0; i < JSON_csw.length; i++)
    {
        table += '<tr id=Row'+ i +'>\
                   <td>' + JSON_csw[i].carerName + '</td>\
                   <td>' + JSON_csw[i].carerAddress + '</td>\
                   <td>' + JSON_csw[i].carerMobile + '</td>\
                   <td>  HISTORY  </td>\
                   <td><button id=btn[' + i + '] \
                   onClick="editGUI('+ i +','+JSON_csw[i].carerName+','+JSON_csw[i].carerAddress+', '+JSON_csw[i].carerMobile+', '+JSON_csw[i].carerID+');">\
                   EDIT</button></td>\
                  </tr>';
    }
```

Doctype declaration;

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

Any help appreciated, I cannot spot the error

Comment: `i` isn't defined in your first snippet of code: `row.innerHTML= '<tr id="Row' + i + '">\ `

Comment: @MarcB thanks I hadn't spotted that. I removed the i but I am still getting the same error

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is being caused due to this line:

```
onClick="editGUI('+ i +','+JSON_csw[i].carerName+','+JSON_csw[i].carerAddress+', '+JSON_csw[i].carerMobile+', '+JSON_csw[i].carerID+');">\
```

When you are sending parameters to the editGUI function in your click handler, you do not have quotes to denote strings. For a sample element in JSON_csw, this is how that line is appended to the html:

```
onClick="editGUI(1,test_name,test_address,test_mobile, 5)"
```

You should enclose the strings in quotes, like:

```
onClick="editGUI('+ i +',\''+JSON_csw[i].carerName+'\',\''+JSON_csw[i].carerAddress+'\', \''+JSON_csw[i].carerMobile+'\', '+JSON_csw[i].carerID+');">\
```

I think it would then work correctly. I haven't tried the above code too, use Inspect Element to see how the onClick handler is actually being shown in the DOM. Then use appropriate escaping and you should be good to go.

Comment: thank you or your answer. I copied in your line and replaced it with mine and I am still getting the same error. I had tried inspecting the element previously and thought that it looked OK. <button id="btn[9]" onclick="editGUI(9,Alika Blackwell,P.O. Box 645, 3333 Iaculis Rd., 0838743615, 570);">       EDIT</button>

Comment: Yeah there are no quotes for strings "Alika Blackwell" etc. Replace \' with \" and try again

Comment: Ok I see. I have replaced as suggested and now receive a different error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }

Comment: FYI it looks like so now: onClick="editGUI('+ i +',\"'+JSON_csw[i].carerName+'\",\"'+JSON_csw[i].carerAddress+'\", \"'+JSON_csw[i].carerMobile+'\", '+JSON_csw[i].carerID+');">\

Answer (score 0):

Unless `carerID` is a number, it must be quoted.  Something like:

```
 row.innerHTML= '<tr id="Row' + i + '">\
                    <td><input type="text" value="' + carerName + '"></td>\
                    <td><input type="text" value="' + carerAddress + '"></td>\
                    <td><input type="text" value="' + carerMobile + '"></td>\
                    <td>  HISTORY  </td>\
                    <td><button onClick="editCarer(\\"'+carerID+'\\");">EDIT</button></td>\
                    </tr>';
```

Note: I did not try this code.  You may have to play around with escaping the quotes.